# iOS app opened from web app with url redirects to Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, url-scheme

I have an iOS app that can be opened using custom URL scheme. When open with the url the app starts receives the data and immediately the Appstore opens on the apps page like it's not installed.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you share your URL scheme?

Answer (score 3):

It will be helpful if you can add some details on iOS version and browser, as both may be responsible to the behaviour you are describing.

In general the behaviour above seems to resemble issues which occur when you are trying to fire a URI Scheme in iOS 9+ using the Safari browser.

I recommend implementing Universal Links which will resolve this permanently.

Some references:
https://www.appsflyer.com/resources/everything-marketer-needs-to-know-deep-linking/universal-links/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links

Comment: The issue is happening with the latest ios version and latest ios safari...

Comment: could the problem be that the app url scheme is of the format appname:///{rest_of_data}. ???

Comment: It is a problem since version 12.3.1, I believe.
I think you'll have to fix this via your click server response, or as mentioned above - move to Universal Links.